Django MSSQL trying to connect with some arbitrary schema rather than dbo
I am deploying a Django service for a client on their Azure env. When switching the DB connector to their Azure SQL DB I get the following error:

django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The specified schema name "b96c7a94-5645-4f7d-ab79-b42d99373823@2fc13e34-f03f-498b-982a-7cb446e25bc6" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. (2760) (SQLExecDirectW)'))

This is weird, becuase I have not specified any schema name in Django, and dbo schema does exists in the client DB.
For example I am able to run a python script with simple queries like this:
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'

or

CREATE TABLE dbo.Example_test (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(50),
Age INT
)

I tried specifing the schema to dbo in the setting like this:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': NAME,  # Initial Catalogue
        'USER': USER,  # Azure Client Id
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,  # Secret Key
        'HOST': HOST,  # Data Source
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'extra_params': 'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal',
            'options': '-c search_path=dbo'
        },
    }
}

but then I get this error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')


What is the default schema for the user you are connecting with? dbo is just a default by convention and can be changed.

@FlipperPA it should be dbo afaik. this is the list of schemas -  dbo
guest
INFORMATION_SCHEMA
sys
db_owner
db_accessadmin
db_securityadmin
db_ddladmin
db_backupoperator
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_denydatareader
db_denydatawriter

Another thing to test; try to telnet to the host and see if it connects. Is the HOST you have defined a FQDN or an IP address? telnet host.example.com 1433. Does it connect or timeout?

This worked for me.
To connect using Service principal you need to use this syntax
For reference check this document.
Make sure you assign these roles to service principal in your DB
DECLARE @USERNAME nvarchar(128)

SET @USERNAME = 'service-principal-name'

BEGIN
    EXECUTE('CREATE USER "' + @USERNAME + '" FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER');
    EXECUTE('ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER "' + @USERNAME + '"');
    EXECUTE('ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER "' + @USERNAME + '"');  
END

settings.py:
import azure.identity as ad

token = ad.ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    client_secret= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    tenant_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)
databaseToken = token.get_token('https://database.windows.net/.default')


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'djangodb',
        'HOST':'djangodb-server.database.windows.net',
        'PORT':'1433',
        'TOKEN': databaseToken.token,
        'OPTIONS':{
            'driver':'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
        }
    }
}


Note:- Using this method Data is not fetched from pre created table


You can fetch data after adding data's to your model

Using pyodbc:
To fetch data from pre created table you need to use pyodbc.
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Users
import pyodbc
import azure.identity as ad
import struct

def fetch_data(request):

    credentials = ad.ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id= "xxxxxxx",
    client_id= "xxxxxx",
    client_secret= "xxxxxxxxxx")


    databaseToken = credentials.get_token('https://database.windows.net/.default')
        
    exptoken = b''
    
    for i in bytes(databaseToken[0], "UTF-8"):
        exptoken += bytes({i})
        exptoken += bytes(1)
    
    tocken_struct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

    Connectionstring ="Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:djangodb-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=djangodb;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
    with pyodbc.connect(Connectionstring,attrs_before = {1256: tocken_struct}) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute('select * from Users')
                data = []
                data = cursor.fetchall()
    
    print(data)
    
    return render(request, 'data.html',{'data': data})

data.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fetch Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Database Records</h1>
    
    <ul>
        {% for record in data %}
        <li>{{ record.UserID }}, {{ record.Username }}, {{ record.Email }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>


Pre-created table

OUTPUT:
Using mssql-django
no data is fetched from table.


Using pyodbc:

